Problem with build react native app, expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin'
I'm getting this error:

Task :expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/FDR/FR_APP/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/defaultmodules/CoreModule.kt:88:21 Unresolved reference: reload
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin'.
A failure occurred while executing
org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details

The build.gradle is this:
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
kotlinVersion = "1.9.0"

The versions are this:
Expo - 51.0.31
React Native - 0.73.5


can we please get a [mcve]?

The issue is with your React Native version, to use expo sdk 51 your react native version should be at least 0.74
"react-native": "0.74.0"

Make sure to update all expo related dependencies to latest if you are using latest expo version
You can use react-native upgrade helper  to upgrade your react native version
